# scanf will not take &(*(p+i).grade)

Tags: c

```
void storing(struct student * p, int count)
{
    int i,j;

    for ( i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        printf("the %d student's info\n", i+1);

        printf("name:\n");
        scanf("%s", p[i].name); 
        printf("age:\n");
        scanf("%d", &((&p[i])->age));  
        printf("grade:\n");
        scanf("%d", &(*(p+i).grade));        
    }
    return;
}
```

I don't know why `scanf` doesn't take `&(*(p+i).grade)`? I know `*(p+i) ≡ p[i]`, but I don't know why it just doesn't work here. I did similar thing with `*(p+i)` in another code I written: `*p.age = 10;` and it successfully writes the value into member `age`.

Comment: It will take `&(*(p + i)).grade`. For the same reason `p->age` is equivalent to `(*p).age` and not `*p.age`.

Comment: You need to learn about [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). I suggest you [get a good beginners book or two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to read.

Comment: There is a good reason why the `[]` and the `->` exist...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did the conversion from `a[b]` to `*(a+b)` correctly, but you missed the precedence of the dot `.` operator vs. the dereference `*` operator.

You need to force the way the operators are evaluated, like this:

```
scanf("%d", &((*(p+i)).grade)); // Add parentheses and keep dot . operator
```

or use `->` operator, like this:

```
scanf("%d", &(p+i)->grade); // Replace dot . with -> operator
```

Note how the use of `->` operator lets you reduce the number of parentheses.

Comment: @aschepler Right, I mixed up the order of parentheses. Thanks!